# sharepoint 2016 access denied issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

First of all, I am trying to retrieve decent webinfo of my web application however I received Access denied error and the error is coming from site collection “sitemaster-a118466c-660d-479c-873f-af6284910724” as screen shot below
[image]

I never create “sitemaster-a118466c-660d-479c-873f-af6284910724” as my site collection, so I suspect it is bundle with “Publishing” template.

Below is the sample code that I use to retrieve my decent webinfo, and I have my access denied error here.

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {


                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteCollectionUrl))
                {

        //code to retrieve my web application decent info

 }
 }
```

[image]

Once I face this I wanted to update ““sitemaster-a118466c-660d-479c-873f-af6284910724” site collection administrator users however I cannot find it from sharepoint centraladmin site.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious... Where is your first screenshot from if not from the central admin site?

Comment: it is from CA site =)

Comment: Please go at Site Collection Features and deactivate the feature: "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"